Problema de lectura de bytes de un archivo excel
he reformulado la pregunta porque omití una parte crucial, tengo un programa en el que leo un archivo excel con un Filepicker que se activa de un botón, el problema surge cuando intenta leer el archivo porque al procesar sys bytes (Uint8List) la variable la manda nulo desconozco por qué
mi código
    ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  ArchivoController archivito = ArchivoController();
                                  await archivito.abrirExcel();
                                  archivito.leerExcel();
                                },
                                child: const Text('child'))

    Future<void> abrirExcel() async {
    try {
      archivo = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ['xlsx'],
        allowMultiple: false,
      );
      //imprimir nombre del archivo
      print(archivo!.files.single.name);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error al seleccionar archivos: $e');
    }
  }

  

    void leerExcel() {
        try {
          if (archivo != null) {
            String key = ''; //clave de inventarioMap
            List<String> valores =
                []; //para almacenar los datos de cada fila excepto su clasificacion
            //se decodifican los bytes del archivo
            Uint8List? bytes = archivo!.files.single.bytes;
            Excel excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes!);// aqui es donde manda error
            Sheet tabla = excel.tables['Sheet1']!;
            for (int i = 0; i < tabla.rows.length; i++) { //itera las filas del xlsx
              List<Data?> row = tabla.rows[i];//lista de cada fila iterada 
              if (row[0] != null) {   //si la PRIMERA celda es diferente de null, es porque contiene su clasificacion
                key = row[0]!.value.toString(); // la clave del mapa de inventario seria su clasificacion
                for (int j = 1; j < row.length; j++) {//j en uno para no capturar su clasificacion
                  if (row[j] != null) {
                    valores.add(row[j]!.value.toString()); //si no es nulo agrega
                  }
                }
                inventarioMap[key] = valores;
                valores.clear();
              }
            }
            descargar(inventarioMap);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print('Error al leer el archivo: $e');
        }
        print(inventarioMap.length);
      }


Primeramente asegura que los datos se carguen en bytes en tu función abrirExcel() usando withData: true, aquí puedes también verificar si en verdad obtienes null, ya que aunque veo que usas await asegurando que terminé abrirExcel() para poder llamar leerExcel(), pero en realidad puedes estar obteniendo un valor null:
Future<void> abrirExcel() async {
  try {
    archivo = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['xlsx'],
      allowMultiple: false,
      withData: true,
    );
    if (archivo != null) {
       print('Archivo seleccionado: ${archivo!.files.single.name} |Bytes: ${archivo!.files.single.bytes != null}');
    } else {
       print('No hubo selección...');
    }
  } catch (e) {
     print('Error: $e');
  }
}


Al final opté por usar el formato a csv, y me funcionó de esa manera pero muchas gracias por el apoyo lo aprecio mucho

Excelente @JorgeMelo , saludos!
